# Glide/Picasso loads only some of the images to Firebase Recyclerview, inside Fragment - using Firebase UI

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am trying to display a list of items which contains images. I'm using firebase UI to initialize a recyclerview inside a fragment.
When I'm running the app only a few of the images are displayed properly but all the others don't. Even if I'm trying to display the same image twice, in one item it shows and in the other, it doesn't. I've tried both Picasso and Glide and the case is the same for both of them.

Any Suggestions?

My FirebaseRecyclerView:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyList, myListViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<...>(
            MyList.class,
            R.layout.my_list_row,
            myListViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(myListViewHolder viewHolder, MyList model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setLink(model.getLink());
            viewHolder.setImage(getContext(), model.getImage());

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
        }
    };



    mList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

//myList class
public static class myListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public myListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }
public void setImage(Context ctx, String image) {

        ImageView gift_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listRowImageView);
       //Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).resize(75,75).into(test_image);
        Glide.with(ctx).load(image).into(test_image);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind image inside your Adapter's OnBindViewholder. I have used Picasso before. Below code works fine in my case -

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StoredNewsListHolder holder, int position) {
    String t = notificationStoreList.get(position).getNotification_title();
    String b = notificationStoreList.get(position).getNotification_content();


    notification_title.setText(t);
    notification_content.setText(b);
    id_hiddenid.setText ( String.valueOf(notificationStoreList.get(position). getId()));
    if(notificationStoreList.get(position).getImage_url() != null){
        Picasso.with(context).load(notificationStoreList.get(position).getImage_url()).into(icon_notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using populateViewHolder.
I'm new to RecyclerView, should I add an OnBindViewholder?
I've added my code to the question.

Comment: `populateViewHolder` is FirebaseUI's variant of `onBindViewHolder`. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L216